# Why does naming array as "name" make .length method print wrong value In JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, naming-conventions

In JavaScript, whenever I name the array variable as "name", the result prints the wrong number. I am wondering why this is happening.

```js
var name = [1, 3, 4];
console.log(name.length);
```

this prints `5` rather than `3`.

Comment: `name` is property from the window object.

Comment: `name` is a built-in global on browsers (it's the name of the current window), and it's always a string. Assigning `[1, 2, 3]` to it converts that array to string, resulting in `"1,2,3"`, which does indeed have `.length` equal to 5.

Comment: [JavaScript Reserved Words](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_reserved.asp)

Comment: OHHHHH! That sounds crystal clear to me! Thank you all!